# HTTP request made by urllib3 and requests library are different

Tags: python-3.x, http, https, python-requests, urllib3

**Goal:** I am trying to scrape some data off a website.

**Problem:** I have to use the **requests** library but it gives me error.

```
import requests
url = "https://www.random.com"
requests.get(url)
```

**Attempt at solution:** I have another program that uses **urllib3** to get website data and it works fine:

```
url = "https://www.random.com"
http = urllib3.PoolManager()
http.request("GET", url)
```

I discovered that **urllib3** and requests uses a common library to send the requests, so I thought I could see what the difference between the two was and maybe change it accordingly. Whilst reading the stack trace below and following it I noticed that **requests** for some reason can't read the response(the code section is from connectionpool.py of one of the library):

```
    def begin(self):
    if self.headers is not None:
        # we've already started reading the response
        return

    # read until we get a non-100 response
    while True:
        version, status, reason = self._read_status()
```

The last line in the above code is where they both differ. **requests** gets an error and does not get any response. **urllib3** gets a response and continues on. My suspicion is that it has to do with the security protocols of **requests**, but I am lost since there are so many variables it sets before sending the response.

Full stack trace of the first piece of code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/path/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 384, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 2, in raise_from
  File "/path/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 380, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "/path/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1321, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/path/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 296, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/path/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 257, in _read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
  File "/path/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 589, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "/path/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 290, in recv_into
    raise SocketError(str(e))
OSError: (104, 'ECONNRESET')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 445, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/path/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 638, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/path/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 367, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "/path/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/path/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/path/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 384, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 2, in raise_from
  File "/homes/ubalgans/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 380, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "/path/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1321, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/path/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 296, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/path/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 257, in _read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
  File "/path/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 589, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "/path/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 290, in recv_into
    raise SocketError(str(e))
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', OSError("(104, 'ECONNRESET')"))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/PycharmProjects/test/reqtest.py", line 8, in <module>
    requests.get(url)
  File "/path/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 72, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/path/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 58, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/path/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 512, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/path/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 622, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/path/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 495, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', OSError("(104, 'ECONNRESET')"))
```

**EDIT:** I enabled logging to see the difference between the two.

requests:

```
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): random.com:443
```

urllib3:

```
    DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): random.com:443
/path/urllib3/connectionpool.py:857: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecureRequestWarning)
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://random.com:443 "GET /request HTTP/1.1" 200 15189
```

Comment: actually, requests code is `http.connection_from_url(url).request("GET", url)`. And i got `Failed to establish a new connection` both of them when i accessed website

Comment: @kcorlidy Could you elaborate on what you mean by that?

Comment: Requests build up connection before request as my first comment, and your urllib3 code set up connection while it is ready to request, but it will be same at last(connection is same only differ on building time) . unfortunately i can not access `https: //random.com` with browser, requests, urllib3. So i can not figure out the reason why you got such error.

Comment: I see. I will work on debugging with that point in mind and come back.